# Smart gwt tutorials and guidance

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, smartgwt

I'm new to smart gwt and I need some help. Please help with some good smart gwt tutorials and also with some good books that i can buy to learn this. I made some search and literally found nothing other than javadocs for it. So please guys, HELP ME!!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For `GWT`, everything it's here, it's your entry point :

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuide

Then for `SmartGWT`, I think everyone should start with the Quick Guide :

http://www.smartclient.com/releases/SmartGWT_Quick_Start_Guide.pdf

Then the showcase it's pretty good, because you have live demos with the code provided :

http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/

Then some others links like :

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/advanced-smartgwt-tutorial-part-1.html 
http://smartgwt-tutorial.blogspot.fr/2011/03/smart-gwt-tutorials.html

Comment: Thanks.... But are there any video tutorials available for Smart GWT? I found good tutorials for GWT on youtube but there were none for Smart GWT...

Comment: Don't know any, the best you will get will be some people talking about, but not tutorials

Comment: The last link listed http://smartgwt-tutorial.blogspot.fr/2011/03/smart-gwt-tutorials.html is dead.

Answer (score 7):

I have learned GWT 2.0 with :

http://www.vogella.com/articles/GWT/article.html
http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/gwt.html

Answer (score 1):

Visit given link which provides you step by step example with explanation.
http://uptick.com.au/content/crud-gwt-gwtp-smartgwt-and-jpa

Comment: This link is dead