# Need Suggestion on Smart GWT

Tags: java, smartgwt

Begin new to Smart GWT framework, I need your valuable comments before I start working on the new project.

1. Do I need to have hands on experience on Java, before working with Smart GWT?
2. Basically, I'm a UI Developer and I don't have much experience in working with java. So is there any good tutorial to learn Smart GWT?
3. What are the basic steps up to learn Smart GWT?

Comment: 1. Yes, the 95% of the code will be in Java
2. The SmartGwt has a great sampler app, there is an example for basically every component it has, however you should get some Java and GWT basics first.
3. See 2.

Comment: Now smartgwt/ smartclient has a feature called componentxml which doesn't need java expertise for ui gwt development. Instead you should have good JavaScript and XML knowledge for ui development. But for server side codes you will need java as per your requirements.
For tutorials, to learn java , use online tutorials like w3schools, guru99, tutorials point etc. For gwt unfortunately we don't have a great tutorial yet. You could still use the showcase in smartclient website and learn viewing the source code and trying by yourself.
Basic steps to learn gwt is , download eclipse, java, gwt framew

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, the Java is necessary for Smart GWT. Despite the fact that you can use declaratively defined datasources for data binding and UI can be modeled by XMLs (UiBinder) a lot of common glue stuff have to be done still in plain old Java.
2. An easy way to learn Smart GWT is to open the [showcase](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase), find an example what you like and click on **View Source** button. If you are a JavaScript devel, you can use directly the SmartClient library, because Smart GWT is a Java wrapper of it.
3. see 2. :)

**Useful links:**

- [forum](http://forums.smartclient.com)
- [FAQ](http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=8159)
- [Start Guide in pdf](http://www.smartclient.com/releases/SmartGWT_Quick_Start_Guide.pdf)
- [Showcase](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase)

Answer (score 0):

Here are my answers to your questions:

1. You do need to have Java skills.
2. Please see #3 below and the stackoverflow link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11538857/smart-gwt-tutorials-and-guidance)
3. Please see the [Smart GWT tutorial page](https://code.google.com/p/smartgwt/wiki/Tutorials)

Comment: 1. is not true It is not just about back-end. Smart GWT is based on GWT, hence all the client-side code is written in Java and compiled to JavaScript.

Comment: SmartClient = **JavaScript** framework (can interact with PHP, ASP.NET, whatever else) But, Smart GWT != SmartClient. Smart GWT is a Java wrapper around SmartClient. And the original question is about Smart GWT.

Comment: @JiriKremser you were correct after looking into it more. I realized you were correct and I also updated the answer. My apologies.